# Comparing images using google custom search api

Tags: comparison, exif, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I've researching for a project and I want to know whether it's possible to compare images to each other using the google custom search api.

Ie, can I upload an image into a program o mine, and with an algorithm I'll provide, search for any photo's using the API , that match the image in terms of exif tags such as: Exif.Photo.ColorSpace , xif.Photo.FocalPlaneXResolution, xif.Photo.FocalPlaneYResolution etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these options are available in JSON API:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

E.g.:
imgColorType
imgDominantColor
imgSize
imgType